# A Featured meta question isn't showing up as "Featured on meta"

Tags: bug, meta

[How is the community doing?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6895/how-is-the-community-doing) is currently [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) (as of 13 hours ago), but not showing up in the **Featured on meta** section of the community sidebar:

[image: "Featured on meta: 2017 moderator election Q&A"]

It is however showing up in the hot meta posts.

Could this be because "hot meta posts" overrides "featured"? I feel like that shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be fixed:

[image: a screenshot of the front page's meta box, in which both "How is the community doing?" and "2017 Moderator Election Q&A" are in the "Featured on Meta" section and only "I just earned the Generalist badge..." is in the "Hot Meta Posts" section.]

Since the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag was added to the question [more than six hours after the post was created](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/6895/3), I speculate that the front page just took a while to notice the change and update itself accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Your hypothesis seems to be correct — [duplicates are prevented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131390/dont-show-meta-posts-that-are-also-linked-as-community-bulletins) in the Community Bulletin space, and [the exact precedence is deliberate but not clearly explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/153219).

Probably, yes, it's just that being Hot overrides being Featured. I personally would do it the other way around, but maybe SE feels that Hotness is more significant than Featuredness.

I do feel like this might instead be a precedence-order bug though, so I'll leave it to a staffer to weigh in with the correct [status-*] tag response and/or an answer.

Comment: It definitely seems like a precedent-order bug, since "featured" feels to me like it ought to be considered more important and relevant than "hot".