# Can a new user answer to comments under their own question?

Tags: support, comments, new-users, privileges

As far as I know you need at least 50 reputation to posts comments on SE. Is it true for commenting your own questions? I thought it was, until I saw a comment to a new user's question:

> ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance

The user had 1 reputation — they presumably couldn't post comments, so now I'm not sure.

Comment: A related questions encourages discussion in comments, although it's quite old: [How can I help a new user reformulate their first question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7196/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Users can always comment on their own questions and answers regardless of reputation, see the end note of [this meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/263383).