# Can we improve the detailed guidance on comments in the Help Center for RPG.SE?

Tags: discussion, help-center

Having read through [the Help again](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), and having found [this meta a nice starting point, I am still not satisfied with the policy guidance on comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3426/22566).

[A concise pieces of policy on comments was written by Brian](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5186/22566) at the end of the [play styles meta answers](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5174/22566).  I think it's been overlooked or lost in the shuffle.  To me, this post gets to the heart of what comments are to be used for.  I'd like to see this post added to the Help on comments, in raw form or perhaps with a bit of editing.    I think that removing most of the second paragraph, as it's "play style content based" or editing it would make it a better phrased policy statement about not arguing in comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, Help pages other than (part of) the [on-topic page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are static and can't be edited.

Brian's statements are useful though and we should probably fold them into a more directly topical FAQ about comments, such as [Why are site comments being deleted?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1174/why-are-site-comments-being-deleted), or (perhaps even better) a new [faq-proposal](/questions/tagged/faq-proposal) like “What should I (not) do if I disagree with an answer?”

Comment: OK, I had forgotten about how little control we have on Help Center guidance.   I think your point in faq proposal may be the better idea.  Thank you.