# Can we color system tags to emphasize that they're different and "more meaningful"?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, game-systems

So, this is kind of an "asking about a problem I don't have" feature, but I wanted to float it out there. As an answerer of unfrequented systems, I've noticed that many questions follow what's come to be expected practice around here - that you tag the system your question is about and you don't have to worry about putting its name anywhere in the title or question body, because everyone will read and recognize the tag.

Except we're a site with a d20 logo and a firebreathing dragon, and not only is D&D the sum total of RPGs to a lot of people, it's houseruled extensively and often enough that I think it's got its own corollary to Poe's Law, in that there is no possible described state of events which hasn't been crowbarred into somebody's D&D game somewhere.

It doesn't help that a lot of RPGs have names which might just refer to a game element or procedure of play: [fate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate) [fiasco](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiasco) [monster-of-the-week](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monster-of-the-week) [dungeon-world](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeon-world) [microscope](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microscope) [kingdom](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom) [follow](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/follow)

Is it possible to give tags that are meant to indicate a game system a different color, such that people can see them and think "oh, this tag is there to mean something important and not for organization purposes"?

Comment: A related feature request: [Make it possible for certain tags (like game tags) to always appear first](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8366/321)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Heh, I saw this question and thought, "Hey, this seems related to my suggestion!" And then I saw that someone else had the same thought. :)

Comment: I've added the [status-review] tag, per this MSE post: [Community and Moderator guidelines for escalating issues via new response process (March 2020)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345032/community-and-moderator-guidelines-for-escalating-issues-via-new-response-proces)

Comment: I laughed out loud when I read this bit- *in that there is no possible described state of events which hasn't been crowbarred into somebody's D&D game somewhere*  -Thanks for the merriment.

Comment: A related request on the Arqade's Meta from back in 2011, which was also [status-declined]: [Make a special tag class for "game tags".](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1651/56295)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on our [current roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/), this isn't work that we will take on, as it doesn't coincide with functional areas that we plan to improve in the near future. We recognize that there's community support for this, but unfortunately, we can't prioritize it at this time.