# Is there a way to ask focused opinion-based questions?

Tags: discussion, policy

For context I want link [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/206189/80177) as the question that inspired me to ask about the possibility for certain types of opinion-based questions.

The question I asked, while having some rules based elements, obviously falls into the opinion-based category. I'm not here to dispute that.

However, this example got me thinking if there is a way to ask for suggestions and best practices for specific situations?

Kind of like how [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) is a place to ask specific types of questions that might fall under the opinion-based category on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). For those unfamiliar, users are directed towards there if they ask more broad "design level" questions or best practices suggestions. In other words: questions that don't have a clear answer but are still useful to ask people with more experience and knowledge, and not just for the one asking the question.

Making a separate space for these kind of questions is probably too niche, as even in the comparison I've given Software Engineering is 1% the size of SO, and SO has multiple such specialised sites to reduce the load it gets. Therefore, in cases like this one, are there existing (or possibly even new) tags that can be utilised to mark and ask such questions?

---

#### EDIT:

[This](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3204/how-do-we-ask-and-answer-subjective-questions) old question about subjective question has been linked in the comments and it offers some good context on the matter as it defines good subjective questions, gives some pointers to what they are, and defines them as generally allowed on the site but also gives pointers on how to answer them.

My question is can this same rule of thumb be utilised but from a question asking perspective (e.g. via a tag) so that it is clear from the start what type of answers should be given. Additionally, this has a chance of reducing arguments of what is and what isn't too opinion-based to be closed as it provides clear guidelines to the mods what to look for.

#### Edit 2:

The linked meta question does answer my question as (per discussion in the comments) all focused questions are treated as always available for good subjective answers.

Comment: Not really, the answer there opens up a possibility for subjective questions to be asked if they are practical and written to lead into constructive and useful information. This opens up the discussion if my linked question falls into that category, but I'm asking if there is a way to avoid this "is it or is it not" edge case by having a mechanism to mark questions that fall into this "no possible factual answer, but still useful and constructive information" category.

Comment: Gotcha - so you are asking if we can have truly opinion-based questions with unsupported answers?

Comment: Yes, specifically the kinds of questions that fall into "tested practices/approaches for situation like X" as a lot of the most useful RPG community knowledge is exactly that. Otherwise we can start feeding rules and official materials to chatbots for most answers.

Comment: Well, "tested practices/approaches for situation like X" is exactly what a good subjective answer is. But it seems like you are asking for untested approaches/practices?

Comment: If you're referring to my original (non-meta) question, that was an error on my part for not specifying that I'm asking for approaches similar to what people used at their tables. That is the kind of stuff I'd like to be able to ask alongside rule based stuff.

Comment: No, this is for the meta question. If you're looking for tested practices, that's exactly what good subjective is. If you're looking for untested, than that's another issue. But if what you want to ask is "how do I resolve X", then you don't need to specify. You'll get answers from rules-based sources if possible and other stackizens may provide good subjective answers. I think maybe the problem is in asking for good subjective? But that might be a mod question.

Comment: If that is the case, then I fail to understand why my non-meta question was closed. Maybe I haven't phrased it as best as I could, but I get the feeling it falls into the "how do I resolve X" category. I get that this should then be a new question about why the original was closed, but I don't have a need for that specific question to be opened, but rather to understand how to ask _"how do I resolve X" questions that are open to subjective answers_ without it seeming like something that should get instantly flagged.

Comment: It's more what I said above in that any and all questions are always available for good subjective answers. You don't need to ask.

Comment: If that is the case that answers my questions. I guess that the question can be closed with the initial linked question you suggested.

Comment: Don't signal edits within the post body. There is the revision history if anybody needs to know what was edited. A post should be presented such that reading it reflects its state. Clarifications can be worked into the text unobtrusively and without calling attention to them.

Comment: @VLAZ: The relevant FAQ on this Meta: [Don't signal your edits in text](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3454/33569)