# Vanished comment - how do I find out what happened?

Tags: support

I thought left a lengthy comment under an answer to this question:

[Without a magic item economy, what is gold for?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47604/without-a-magic-item-economy-what-is-gold-for)

Which now seems to have vanished. There's no record of my either posting it (or a mod deleting it).

Did I imagine it? If not, how can I find out what happened to it. And while I'm here, how can I link to a particular answer, rather than just the question?

Comment: By *no record* you mean you checked your your profile's activity and there's no listing of your comment there, either?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yep. That's what made me wonder if I'd just imagined posting it. Or, more likely, that something went wrong when I hit return.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, when a mod deletes a comment it is just gone. I've had a *lot* of comments deleted (I have a tendency to get involved in comment conversations) and I've never seen a trace of the comment or any record of it's existence. So a mod has probably deleted your comment, and I don't think there's anything you can do about that. A mod *can* see and potentially restore deleted comments, so if you really want to know what happened or try to get your coment back you can ask one of the mods to check for you. The best way to do that is to ping one (probably mxyzplk, he's the most active), in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat).

For more information on this, check the [deleted-comments](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deleted-comments) tag on [Meta Stack Exchange.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deleted-comments) There's a lot of questions and answers there on similar issues.

Each answer has the share, edit and flag links under it, just like a question. If you click share, you'll be given a link you can copy which goes directly to that answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I see there are only 3 mods, although I can't see a way they're open for contact. So if one should wander by here, I'd be interested to know *why* that comment was deleted.

Comment: @MattThrower Apparently all RPG.SE moderators get pinged for all RPG.meta Qs, so they'll see this as soon as they log in. Mods rarely delete comments unless a citizen flags them, so if you look at [the comment flag reasons](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ExaSU.png) you might get a sense for why someone might have flagged it!

Comment: Not irrevocably. Mods have both a history and the ability to restore comments.

Answer (score 7):

Comments are meant to be ephemeral and are often deleted on this site.  See [Why are site comments being deleted?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1174/why-are-site-comments-being-deleted)

Comments are for improving/clarifying questions and answers. Answers are the value here on the site.  Threads of comments obscure answers and are therefore are on the chopping block.

That's a general answer; after looking I found your comment on gatherer818's answer:

> I was going to add an answer very much like this. The problem is that the difference between magic item trade in 44 and 5e appears vast. But there are happier mediums. Simply put: sure you can buy and sell magic items for gold, but the sums involved are going to be astronomical. Yet adventuring can yield astronomical sums eventually. So if your PC wants to buy something, they can, but they're going to have to save the proceeds of several adventures (at least) to afford it.

That's a fine comment but not going to be kept forever.  It's a combination of +1, plus an opinion on a magic item economy which isn't really the point of the question. Gatherer could have incorporated your point into his answer but didn't; therefore it got deleted during cleanup after a couple days. I don't intend to undelete it; you could contribute an answer to the question if you want a permanent thought contributed (though do note that the question is asking about something a little different).

For further context, this question has had something like 50 comments on it, half of which have been deleted. I just deleted another 10 while in there. When questions get people into chatty forum mode, we have to crank the comment weedeater up to a higher pitch than we would on an arbitrary question, so that the question and answers get adequate "screen time" and it's not a big reddit-like mess of people hobnobbing with each other.