# Stop deleting valid comments because you don't like them

Tags: discussion

On this answer here:  https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/65542/2064

A definition is given of  a word.  That definition is NOT provided by the text of the book being referenced.  My comment alerting readers to this fact is being deleted.

If you are going to quote the book, quote the book accurately, and stop trying to hide the fact that you are doing so!

My comment for the record, which keeps getting deleted is:

> "The definition of the word provided here does not match the one provided by the PHB, please make that more clear."

This back and forth of deleting relevant comments is getting ridiculous.

I attempted to make it more clear by having the source include only the actual table in the book, instead of the paragraph defining "Trinkets".  That also was reverted, despite there being no items on page 159.

Using mod privileges to erase comments that are perfectly valid, seems frankly quite harmful to the site.

Comment: What would you call deleting my comment 3+ times?

Comment: Is this meta about the content dispute, or is it about the comments? You should clarify that in your meta question. (If it's about the comments being deleted, then it's a duplicate of [Why are site comments being deleted?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1174), so you may want to revise this to focus on the content dispute.)

Comment: This is about you abusing your privledge to delete comments you dont like.

Comment: @GMNoob mxyzplk deleted the first set, without any prompting or contact from me. I deleted the 4 after the "stop arguing" directive, as they were ignoring a directive from a mod. That mxyzplk and I managed to cooperate on this without actually speaking to each other is due to it being a really straightforward application of current site policy on what comments are and aren't for.

Comment: The fact that you aren't even willing to admit that the table only exists on pages 160 and 161, really just takes the cake.

Comment: @GMNoob You have perhaps not noticed the edit I made in response to that comment?

Comment: A ststment of fact and a request for clarification is not an argument.  Deleting comments which are valid is infuriating!

Comment: @GMNoob If you're infuriated, you should probably take a bit of a walk and get some fresh air. You've presented your issue and you'll need to wait a bit before a proper community response gathers anyway.

Comment: I did not, my apologies.

Comment: Or you could just make it clear that you are not quoting the book.

Comment: Thanks. The choice to include 159 was deliberate, but I failed to adjust the wording around it to match and it was useful to point out the discrepancy. (If knowing it helps at all, that comment I only deleted after making the edit it inspired, and I deleted it as "obsolete", which is the nearest thing a deleted comment has to a "useful" marker.)

Answer (score 16):

You suggested an improvement to an answer and it was declined by the answerer.

When that happens, the comment should get flagged as obsolete by the answerer and the responding moderator will delete it unless the comment's been upvoted in the meantime. **No part of this process requires the answerer to be a moderator**; it'd work the same way for you or me or anybody else who uses the comment-flagging system. When the person flagging them as obsolete is the person who wrote the answer, "deleting comments because you don't like them" is kinda basic protocol.

Why should the comment get flagged and deleted? Because we know that ["when users start adding important, useful, and interesting information in the commentary, you break down that structure of 'one question, best answer.'"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1174/4398) Leaving the info in a comment means stranding information you think is useful in a non-searchable, non-votable part of the site! If you feel the info is important enough to preserve, the thing to do is (as you have) to make it part of your own answer--and downvote the other answer if you think leaving out that info makes it worthy of such action. The Stack's outlet for "But you're wrong!" is downvoting and giving better answers.

(And anyway, once a user declines to fold a comment's information into her answer, repeating the suggestion probably won't make her re-consider.)

Comment: mxyzplk answer isn't really relevant, as he is referring to completely different comments.  The only information in my comment which is relevant, is the fact that the answer appears to be quoting the PHB, but it is not, and that should be made more clear.

Comment: @GMNoob I'm basing this solely on your description of the situation, I didn't see the other comments. You made a suggestion to improve the answer and it was declined. That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: To avoid confusion I've removed the quote and used my own words.

Answer (score 6):

Being agitated about a point of game rules does not entitle you to:

1. Argue in comments - I deleted a big ol' thread of back and forth and repeating yourselves.
2. Ignore mod directives - I said stop arguing in comments and I meant it.

Your comment has been declined as an improvement by the poster of that answer. If you feel strongly about it put it in your own answer. You have, now the community can vote.

Continuing to argue in comments after this point will result in specific further mod action you will not like. Even if it is the most important point ever made in the world. You should probably take a walk AFK and get some perspective.

Comment: Thanks for not explaining how stating that something appears to be a quote but isn't is considered arguing.

Comment: posting 8 comments to the same effect on a single question is arguing.  It's another of those darn dictionary definitions. And what's more is I'm telling you it is. One comment to that effect left alone would have been fine. But it has gone way past that into arguing. So now commenting privileges on that answer have gone away. It's all very, very simple.

Comment: You are not talking about the comment in my question. You are refering to other irrelevant comments.

Comment: All part of the same argument. A valid comment, repeated again and again, becomes an argument. Therefore while the comment is valid to make, you have made it invalid by context and thus had it removed (In addition to the "the poster declines it, put it in your own answer" effect).