# Should answerers and querents flag comments they folded in?

Tags: discussion, comments

According to the consensus over on [Why are site comments being deleted?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1174/why-are-site-comments-being-deleted), comments that have been folded in to a question or answer are eligible to be deleted because they are Obsolete. This helps to keep the site clean and canonical.

Does this mean that users editing a question or answer to include information from comments should then mark those comments as Obsolete?

Answer (score 16):

Yes, and that is frequently done.