# What is the delete comment policy?

Tags: discussion, comments

I've just noticed several of my comments are gone and I didn't delete them. I don't comment lightly - it's generally looking for clarification from a question or response, or to point out issues in response. I will delete my own comments once I think the issue is resolved, but many are deleted, presumably by a moderator, while the issue still stands, implying I now no longer take issue with the response. That seems awful cavalier and defeats the "community" spirit.

Comment: It is almost. However, this case "deleting rejected suggestions" is not covered.

Comment: Fourth paragraph in the faq: "Comments suggesting changes get tidied up after a while too if the post author rejects the suggestion."

Answer (score 5):

The comment deletion policy is in [Why are site comments being deleted?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1174/why-are-site-comments-being-deleted) and is guided by the "When should I comment?" and "When *shouldn't* I comment?" sections of the [help article about the commenting feature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Those two comments were removed as being no longer constructive — the post author rejected the suggested change, and having no further purpose, the temporary notes were removed.

Comment: If the author agrees to the change, the comment is no longer relevant. However, if a post author rejects a change suggested in a comment, then the comment provides value/insight that is not in the answer and thus "being no longer constructive" is an incorrect assessment.

Comment: To make sure your insight stays viewable on the question, you can either suggest an edit to the answer you have issues with; or you can write your own, competing answer that includes highlighting the point of contention.

Comment: @Wyrmwood Comments aren't for hanging a scarlet letter on a post. At that point, the correct thing to do is downvote and close the browser tab.

Comment: @Weaveworker89 Cleaning up comments is the janitorial function that mods are duty bound to perform.  Mine, as precious as I pretend that they are, are no better than dust in the wind.  That's how SE works, when it works.  (Please do not go to History.SE ... please ...)

Comment: Janitorso remove trash, censors remove dissenting information.

Comment: @Wyrmwood If we were in the business of removing dissenting information, we'd be preventing you from submitting your information in an answer right now. We're not doing that. We do regularly remove obsolete comments though, because [the purpose of comments is to be removed](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), and our job is moderation, not censoring. If the distinction between information removed for moderation purposes and information removed for censoring purposes is unclear, I suggest pondering that koan to avoid experiencing further disappointments here.