# Why do my answers and comments keep getting shut down because I say "thank you"?

Tags: support, answers, comments, deleted-answers

Every time I post an answer to my question or someone makes a small suggestion I respond and then I say something along the lines of "Thanks" or "Thank you". This ends up in my answer/comment getting deleted. Why is this?

Answer (score 11):

#### Answers must answer the question.

From the [help center article on answer deletion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) (italics mine):

> Answers that **do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed**. This includes answers that are:
>
> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - *“thanks!” or “me too!” responses*
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - barely more than a link to an external site
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

For comments, see here: [Why are site comments being deleted?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1174)