# Why was a comment about etymology removed?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/204824/23547) about the origin of the name Yan-C-Bin has so far attracted only one answer.  [That answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/204833/23547) makes the claim that all of the names of the Princes of Elemental Evil were made up "wholecloth" with "no mythological/cultural callback".

While I thought that might be possible for Yan-C-Bin, it was clearly not true for at least some of the Princes, whose names incorporate Greek and Latin roots that match their aspects.  I said as much in a comment.  The comment has since been deleted.

I thought my tone was respectful, and I don't think the comment is no longer needed, since as of this writing the answer still makes the claim.  I am pretty sure I actually posted the comment, because I initially posted noting the roots "hydr" and "cryo" and then within 5 minutes edited to add "ogre"; I would not have been able to edit had the first comment not posted.

I am at a loss as to why my comment was deleted.

Comment: Sounds like the moderator thought your comment was more of an answer, and based on your explanation here, I think I agree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are site comments being deleted?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1174/why-are-site-comments-being-deleted)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov the comment was *not related to the question*. It was only relevant about *the answer*. The answer made a claim about other names *unrelated* to the one in the question. The comment pointed out the claim seemed incorrect for those. In what way does that answer the question? IMO, were this to be posted as an answer, I'd vote it NAA and I think such an answer would indeed be removed. Because it's irrelevant.

Comment: @VLAZ I don’t know exactly what the comment said, I’m just basing it off of what Kirt has described here, which seems to be evidence or part of some sort of answer, which is something our “do not answer in comments” FAQ says will be deleted. But it doesn’t matter, any and all comments are subject to deletion by design.

Comment: I feel like this one is worth leaving to the mods to provide the exact reason.

Comment: The comment seems to have been restored now.

Comment: Multiple users flagged the comment as "no longer needed". Users sometimes use such flags to get rid of comments that *are* adding value, but that the flagging user does not like. The mods try to check each flag to avoid deleting comments in such cases, but we don't always have time to fully investigate each comment, and it looks like your comment slipped through the cracks.

Comment: @ObliviousSage Nope, I don’t agree that this “slipped through the cracks.” That is a worthless comment, and definitely shouldn’t have been _restored_.

Comment: This discussion should not be deleted. The comment should be.

Comment: I'm not satisfied with either of the current answers to this question, nor, given its specific nature, do I think it is a duplicate of the question suggested. ObliviousSage's [comment](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12394/why-was-a-comment-about-etymology-removed?noredirect=1#comment42702_12394) that multiple users flagged the comment as 'no longer needed' is helpful, and may be as much resolution as I can hope for.

Comment: Since the instigating comment has now been restored, there is less value to me in knowing the answer - my main concern was that my comment could have been taken as rude / offensive, and no one has suggested that so far. What is etiquette in this case - do I leave _this_ question with no answer selected, or self-delete it?

Comment: @Kirt It's fine to just leave it be, you don't need to do anything further.

Comment: *has so far attracted only one answer*
This has now been overcome by events. There are two answers.  One of them went to the source.  The original one was right, he made it up; that's from the horse's mouth.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Thank you - good to hear that the original question has been resolved.

Answer (score 11):

#### All comments are subject to deletion, by design.

Naturally, I cannot comment on the exact reason your particular comment was deleted, since I neither know what it said, nor have the button to delete it. However, we often see users approaching comments with the expectation that comments have some sort of permanence as long as they follow the rules, and this is simply not the case. From the [comments privileges page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) (emphasis mine):

> #### What are comments?
>
> Comments are *temporary "Post-It" notes* left on a question or answer. They can be upvoted (but not downvoted) and flagged, but do not generate reputation. There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good.

By design, *all* comments are subject to deletion, at moderator discretion (usually, there are some automated systems that delete comments based on user flags). So you should have no expectations that any comment you post will be left up permanently. See this post for a number of reasons why your comment may have been selected for deletion: [Why are site comments being deleted?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1174/why-are-site-comments-being-deleted) It was probably for one of the reasons listed there.

Answer (score -9):

Because it’s unnecessary pedantry. It does not suggest any improvement to the answer, and it does not add any value being left there as is.

It seems utterly implausible that anyone reading that question would be unaware of the meanings of “hydro” or “cryo.” No one is suggesting that the author invented those meanings, or just happened to coincidentally fall on those roots in their made-up name. No one reading it is ever going to get that impression. The answer clearly is referring to the specific usage of those roots, the “*names*” that are actually what the answer claims to have been made up, and there is zero reason to “clarify” on that point, either in the answer or in a comment.

The comment **should** be deleted, and should stay that way.

Comment: Re: 'No one is suggesting that the author invented those meanings'  I'm pretty sure the author of that answer is suggesting just that, even if inadvertently with sloppy wording. 
 "The creator of the Princes of Elemental Evil, Lewis Pulsipher, made it up wholecloth, **just as he made up Olhydra, Imix, Ogremoch, and Cryonax. No mythological/cultural callback to be found.**"

Comment: @Kirt Yes, Pulsipher made up those _names_. There is no basis in real-world myths or cultures for those names. The text specifically refers to the _names_ as being made up. That he used etymological roots is 1. obvious, and 2. irrelevant. No claim is made that Pulsipher invented those roots. This is pedantry. It isn’t helping anyone or anything. If you had suggested an edit along these lines, it should be rejected as making no improvement whatsoever.

Comment: Actually, on further consideration I think that comment is revealing a deep flaw in the answer. The other elemental prince names are all basically the fantasy equivalent of "Joe Earthface", "Bubba Waterpants", and "Sally Firehair". It's easy to take the word roots used in their names to make that case. Yan-C-Bin *doesn't* follow that pattern, though, which suggests there may be some other inspiration.

Comment: @ObliviousSage How is that a flaw in the answer? The answer says that, if there was some other inspiration, it isn’t to be found in any of the sourcebooks. That’s a valid answer. Reasons to suspect another inspiration are kind of irrelevant; of course we have reason to suspect inspiration from somewhere, that’s why the question was asked in the first place. If anything, that should be added to the _question_, as motivation for asking after the one name and not the others. But that still seems unnecessary, because questions don’t have to justify themselves like that.

Comment: I understand that the names themselves are unique and original creations.  But the claim is made that they contain no mythological or cultural callbacks.  If deliberately including elements like 'hydr' (found in the Greek and D&D monster Hydra), 'cryo' (found in the D&D monster cryohydra), and ogre (found in the RW and D&D ogre and Orcus) is _not_ a mythological / cultural callback', I would like to understand what _is_ one?  Could you help me understand what the names would have to do to actually count as callbacks for you?

Comment: The answer claims that it's a made-up name that does not reference anything and has no deeper meaning, *just like the other elemental prince names*. The fact that the other elemental prince names follow a pattern and Yan-C-Bin breaks that pattern makes that claim suspect. The asker didn't ask if the *books* mention the names being references, it asked if they *are* references. The fact that the books don't mention it just means they aren't helpful for answering the question.

Comment: My contention is that their research was focused on *the books*. **If** the asker had asked about the books then that would be a great answer... **but that's not what they asked for**. It is a designer-reasons question, and so an answer that claims there is no deeper meaning should rest on a quote from the designer. If they were claiming the name *was* a reference to something there are lots of other ways to support that, but to claim that it **doesn't** reference anything only a quote from the designer is definitive.

Comment: "*Literally every book published on the subject is “one tiny bit” to you?*" let me answer this with a question - if you go to Scotland and see a black sheep, would you decalre that all sheep in Scotland are black? Or that the sheep you've seen *so far* are black? That's really the difference here - the question is whether or not the name has any cultural or mythological meaning. Going through all *sourcebooks* tells you there isn't anything *in the souircebooks*. Not that there are no cultural or mythological roots.

Comment: Else you are trying to argue here that the titular "dragons" from D&D also entirely self-contained entities, if no D&D book mention a real world origin. Is *this* what you're arguing here? That the sole and only way for something to *have* cultural and mythological connections is if they are explicitly written about in a sourcebook? Do think about how much sense that makes. Because it doesn't. Meta materials and knowledge *do* exist outside sourcebooks.

Comment: If someone asks "what do the books say about X", an answer of "I've read all the books even remotely related to X cover-to-cover and none of them say anything about it" is a *great* answer. But when someone asks "is X related to anything outside the game" an answer of "the game books don't say X is related to anything outside the game, so it must not be" is a pretty bad answer. I could be convinced that it isn't an answer *at all*.

Comment: @ObliviousSage 1. your point has *nothing* to do with the comment being discussed, since it raises *none* of these concerns, it’s just pedantry. 2. your position is wildly at odds with historical practice on this site, and again, is only going to mean that people who have done exhaustive research aren’t going to bother sharing it with the site. That’s how the site dies.

Comment: Honestly, this is yet another straw on the "let's re-ban designer-reasons questions" camel-back. The site handles questions where deep knowledge of the rulebooks is valuable quite well. It handles questions about whether some random person has ever mentioned X... *less* well.

Comment: The question is a poor fit for this site, resulting in it drawing a bad answer, and the comment was valuable because it lead me to think about why the Q and A were both bad.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I will say, emphatically—with acknowledgment that it is opinion, but it is an opinion rooted in expertise—that you are _wrong_. It’s not a bad question. It’s not a bad answer. It’s a bad premise to have that the only acceptable way to answer is with a statement from the designer. That isn’t—and has never been—true. Answers have to be backed up. Speculative answers are bad. Answers that are based in deep expertise are good. Answers that are backed up—even if the backing up falls short of some Platonic ideal—are good. Accessing that expertise is the point of the site.

Comment: @ObliviousSage The site you seem to be imagining is, quite simply, not valuable. No one would be particularly interested in it. Indeed, as we become that site more and more, more and more people _aren’t_ interested in it. You should perhaps think more about what kind of site you want to have—and what value that would provide—and less about establishing and rigidly enforcing arbitrary rules. The point of any rules here is to encourage expertise and avoid speculation. Neither Q nor A here has any problems with either facet.

Comment: The only acceptable "no" answer to a "is X a reference to something outside the game" question is a quote from the designer. It could be a reference to a running joke from the designer's home campaign, and no amount of research other than asking the designer will ever reveal that. I am of the opinion that that makes the answer in this case a bad answer, and further of the opinion that questions where most people would suspect the answer is no but only a no from the designer can be definitive are bad questions for this site because they don't reward RPG expertise.

Comment: To be clear: If the answer to the question was "**yes**, it's based on X and here's the references to show the relationship" then that would *not* require a quote from the designer; there's tons of other ways to support such an answer. It's only the "no, it's not based on anything" that requires such definitive support.

Comment: And that definitive support is required precisely *because* the asker did not limit their question to the rulebooks. If they had, then an answer of "the rulebooks never say anything about it" would be fine again.

Comment: @ObliviousSage When we banned designer-reasons questions, we said we could trivially edit them to not be about designer reasons—for instance, to ask about what’s in the books. When we unbanned designer-reasons questions, it was in part because that wasn’t happening. In both cases, the understanding was that this is a *trivial reframing of the question*. There is zero need to decide that “The only acceptable ‘no’ answer to ‘is X a reference to something outside the game’ question is a quote from a designer.” That isn’t the consensus, and that doesn’t add anything useful to the site.

Comment: Those trivial reframings could generally give the asker what they were really looking for. When someone asks "why does the game not allow X", an answer to "what would be the mechanical impact of removing the rule against X" is usually going to explain things in a way that resolves what the asker is looking for. Reframing this question from "is the name Yan-C-Bin a reference to something" to "do the source books mention whether the name Yan-C-Bin is a reference to something" does not result in answers that solve the asker's problem (except in the rare case where the answer is "yes, on page Y").

Comment: If there was a Chinese mythological figure named Yang Zhi Wen who could summon storms, and the rulebooks simply didn't mention them, an answer saying "the rulebooks don't mention it being a reference to anything, so it's not a reference to anything" would be more obviously wrong.

Comment: @ObliviousSage Got it. The plan for the site going forward is to tear down all the Good so that the Perfect can finally win the fight. I’d love to know whose decision that was and why they had the authority to make it, but regardless, message is hard, loud and clear.

Comment: I can see why people *like* that question, even though I don't think it's a good fit for the site, and the community has voted to allow designer-reasons questions so I'm leaving it be. It's blowing my mind, though, that you think the answer is a good answer.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I feel like "design reasons" is a red herring. The author used a name because they wanted to produce a product and get paid. Mystery solved. It doesn't actually answer the question, though. Because it doesn't matter what the designer wanted. This is a research-based question. The answer is one of "Yes, there is an identifiable root <explanation>" or "No, there is no identifiable root". The latter is harder to prove but not impossible, either. Consider [tracing origin of symbols](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/193118) as analogous. Still doesn't matter what the authors intended.

Comment: Pulsipher has answered, and his answer is "I made them up" - which makes much of this comment stream seem, to me, to be overcome by events.